# PHP compare subsequent array element to previous

Tags: php, arrays, ebay-api

So i'm having trouble getting a bit of code to work. Essentially what I want to do is:

in a foreach loop, if a given array value is set, compare that existing value to the current loop value, then set the existing value = current value (for the iteration) if the existing value is already greater than current val. Here is the code i'm working with:

```
if ($usedebayxml->ack == 'Success') {
    foreach($usedebayxml->searchResult->item as $key => $value) {
        if(isset($newarray[1]['TotalCost'])) {
            if($newarray[1]['TotalCost'] > ((integer)$value->shippingInfo->shippingServiceCost + (integer)$value->sellingStatus->currentPrice)) {
                $newarray[1]['Title'] = (string)$value->title ;
                $newarray[1]['ShippingCost'] = (integer)$value->shippingInfo->shippingServiceCost;
                $newarray[1]['Price'] = (integer)$value->sellingStatus->currentPrice;
                $newarray[1]['Condition'] = 'New';
                $newarray[1]['TotalCost'] = (integer)$value->shippingInfo->shippingServiceCost + (integer)$value->sellingStatus->currentPrice;
            }
        }
        else
            $newarray[1]['Title'] = (string)$value->title;
            $newarray[1]['ShippingCost'] = (integer)$value->shippingInfo->shippingServiceCost;
            $newarray[1]['Price'] = (integer)$value->sellingStatus->currentPrice;
            $newarray[1]['Condition'] = 'Used';
            $newarray[1]['TotalCost'] = (integer)$value->shippingInfo->shippingServiceCost + (integer)$value->sellingStatus->currentPrice;
    }
}
```

With this code, what is returned is ultimately the values in the LAST key object in the xml file (im using simpleXML if that helps). In other words, i don't think the first if block (if isset) is being entered into, and the values are being set to whatever the values are for the current iteration. Can anyone see any flaw in my logic here? I've been stumped on this one for a while.

Comment: I am a supreme idiot. The logic here is fine, i was just missing a { for the opening else block. dur! After adding this, this bit of code works as intended :)

Answer (score 0):

I am a supreme idiot. The logic here is fine, i was just missing a { for the opening else block. dur! After adding this, this bit of code works as intended :)

I'm surprised though that i wasn't throwing any errors without having this....I think that was probably throwing me off in determining why it wasn't working originally.